# Generate number and Display Matrices

Tags: c, matrix

i'm woundering why this code is not working, I want to generate random numbers from 1-10 and insert in matrice and to print them. Matrice is 3x3 dimension:

```
int main(){
srand(1);
int i,j;
int mat[3][3];

for(i<0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        mat[i][j]=rand()%9+1;
    }
}

for(i<0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("%2d",mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
 for(i<0;i<3;i++){
     ^^^
```

it should be

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
```

Otherwise, you end up using uninitialized local variable `i` value, which leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).